# Oracle 11g User account locking frequently

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am getting the account locked error (ORA-28000: the account is locked) frequently.

When I unlock user account by the command "ALTER USER system account UNLOCK" temporarily it will be ok. After some time the same account lock happen.

this issue started after the changing the password.
i am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64
bit.

can some one please help.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Vinay

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general database tech support. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Something somewhere has the old password.  It tries to log in, gets an error, and retries.  Eventually, your account is locked.  Find that something and fix it.  If you have logging enabled in your listener or you audit failed login attempts, that may help you figure out what has the old password.

Comment: Take a look at the value of `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME`, `PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME` and/or `FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` in profile(s) assigned to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the audit trail to find the culprit:

```
select returncode, os_username, userhost, terminal, dba_audit_trail.*
from dba_audit_trail
order by timestamp desc;
```

In the long-run you probably want to avoid using the SYSTEM account as much as possible.  Administrators should have their own account for most tasks, and applications should have a less-privileged account.

Answer (score 0):

@Vinay,

You can change PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME parameter by using below command.

```
alter profile default limit PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME  unlimited;
```